# Como setar dois (ou mais) parâmetros css de uma só vez?

Tags: css

Gostaria de saber se é possível, em um cenário onde os dois valores fossem iguais. Faria isso para adiantar a escrita.

Por exemplo, passar `HEIGHT` e `WIDTH` juntos: `height, width: 50px;`

Tentei fazer assim, mas não funcionou...  Alguém?

Comment: Tudo que é possivel fazer com essas propriedades está documentado aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O máximo que você pode fazer é guardar o valor em uma variável:

```css
div {
  --size: 30px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[Mais sobre variáveis no CSS](https://tableless.com.br/como-usar-variaveis-no-css-de-forma-nativa/).

[**Suporte**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables).

Mais recursos necessitarão de um pré-processador.